# Java: How to RegEx or Substring Utils this String?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, string-utils

```
"Current Peak :   830           300"
```

How can I get hold of the two numbers, but without the spaces. (There are 5 or more spaces in between each substring)

Using apache's StringUtils I got so far:

```
String workUnit =
StringUtils.substringAfter(thaString,
":");
```

This gives back:

```
"830           300"
```

but still with a lot of spaces and not separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but this should give you your two numbers:

```
String[] workUnits = StringUtils.split(StringUtils.substringAfter(thaString, ":"));
```

Comment: Perfect! System.out.println(workUnits[i]); gives back the resp. values. I liked your first solution (edited away) w/o apache's library, String [] temp = myArray[3].split(" "); however System.out.println(temp[temp.length-1]); gave only back the last number ..

Answer (score 6):

Or just using core java:

```
    String input = "Current Peak :   830           300";
    String[] parts = input.split("\\s+"); // Split on any number of whitespace
    String num1 = parts[3]; // "830"
    String num2 = parts[4]; // "300"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("Current Peak :\\s*(\\d*)\\s*(\\d*)");
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher("Current Peak :   830           300");
if (matcher.find()) {
    String first  = matcher.group(1); // 830
    String second = matcher.group(2); // 300
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] workUnits = StringUtils.substringAfter(thaString,":").split("\\s+");
```